# regex matching in splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm trying to match regular expression say **29f4b320-ae87-44b3-8834-509d0505c12e**
this kind of number.

I'm providing user a text box where he might enter numbers like c12e ,  -44b3-  etc.
and it should match as whole and event if these exists as  part. since above two inputs exist in 29f4b320-ae87-44b3-8834-509d0505c12e it should match.
but in case of beginning with hyphen or ending with hyphen its ignoring.
How to ignore hyphen and still match?

Xml code

```
<view onunloadCancelJobs="False" autoCancelInterval="100">
<label>Search</label>

<!-- Beginning of Chrome -->
<module name="AccountBar" layoutPanel="appHeader" />
<module name="AppBar" layoutPanel="navigationHeader"/>
    <module name="SideviewUtils" layoutPanel="appHeader" /> 
     <module name="Message" layoutPanel="messaging">
  <param name="filter">*</param>
  <param name="clearOnJobDispatch"> False</param>
  <param name="maxSize">1</param>
</module> 
<module name="TitleBar" layoutPanel="viewHeader">
 <param name="actionsMenuFilter">dashboard</param> 
</module>

<!-- End of Chrome -->
<module name="HiddenSearch" layoutPanel="mainSearchControls">
    <param name="search">sourcetype=insight/insight.lntinfotech/INSPRODSP *$target$*</param>
    <module name="ExtendedFieldSearch">
 <param name="intention">
 <param name="name">stringreplace</param>
 <param name="arg">  
   <param name="target">
      <param name="default">500</param>
   </param>
  </param>
 </param>
 <param name="replacementMap">
 <param name="arg">
<param name="target">
<param name="value"></param>
</param>
</param>
</param>
<param name="field">Wildcard search</param>
 <module name="EventsViewer" layoutPanel="resultsAreaLeft">
<param name="segmentation">full</param>
</module>
</module>
</module>
</view>
```

Comment: What makes this a regex issue? I can't even find the regex here.

Comment: Hi melwil,
In this line from above code <param name="search">sourcetype=insight/insight.lntinfotech/INSPRODSP *$target$*</param>
$target$ gives whatever user enters and i'm specifying zero or any(* asterisk) before and after $target$. and i need search this in a field so i wrote like this 

sourcetype=insight/insight.lntinfotech/INSPRODSP CorrelationID = *$target$*, it works for input like 12, 343 but if user enters value like -44b3- then its not matching even though the field has value like 29f4b320-ae87-44b3-8834-509d0505c12e these. How to match these inputs(like -44b3- )?

Comment: What I'm really asking is what this has to do with regex. As far as I can tell, no real regex is being used here? you are just doing a search with wildcards?

Comment: Yeah you're right, now i'm just using wildcards. In order to match hyphen separated numbers this above wild card is not working? so do i need regex for this? i've not used regex that much. can this be sovled using just wildcards or do i need regex?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some quotations around the `*$target$*`.